# Angular reactive foms ngfor can't set inputs value

Tags: angular, typescript

I am doing inline editing, i get my data from server, i am trying to set my inputs value with object i got from API, but for the parent element (CatEdit) value is same for every input, and for the child (carPartSubCategories) it is empty, what am i doing wrong?

**.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
      <form [formGroup]="CatEdit">
      <input type="text" formControlName="name"  [value]="item.name" />
    </form>
  <div *ngFor="let c of item.carPartSubCategories; let j = index;">
  <span class="value"> {{c.name}}</span>
  <form [formGroup]="subCatEdit">
  <input type="text" [value]="c.name" formControlName="name" />
</form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
    this.items = [
        {
          name: 'test name',
          carPartSubCategories: [
            {
              name: 'test sub 1 ',
            },
            {
          
              name: 'test sub 2',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: 'test name 2',
          carPartSubCategories: [
            {
              name: 'test sub 4',
            },
            {
              name: 'test sub 5',
            },
          ],
        },
      ]

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.CatEdit = this._formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
    });

    this.subCatEdit = this._formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
  this.items.forEach(x => {
    this.CatEdit.patchValue({
      name: x.name
    });
    this.subCatEdit.patchValue({
      name: x.carPartSubCategories.name
    });
  })
```

Comment: hi! thanks for the comment, inputs value is same for item.name and for the c.name it is empty, i want to have inputs value same as top value it has

Comment: @GRD thank you so much! one more question,carPartSubCategories also has a id so i need to pass to my click function also that, how cani do that? also please post your answer so i can upvote you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some confusion in your code.
On the html template you are iterating over the `items` but you always use the same instance of the formGroup named `CatEdit` (this is why you see the value "test name 2" set on both inputs).
What I recommend is to create a container-type `FormArray` whose controls are `FormGroup` that represent the single element of the `items` list.

```
carContainer: FormArray;
....
this.carContainer = this._formBuilder.array(
  this.items.map((item) => this._getFormGroup(item))
);
....
private _getFormGroup(item: Car) {
  return new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(item.name),
    carPartSubCategories: new FormArray(
      item.carPartSubCategories.map(
       (carPart) => new FormControl(carPart.name)
      )
    ),
  });
}
```

On the html template you just need to do the following

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of carContainer.controls">
 <form [formGroup]="group">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" />
   <div
     style="margin-left: 20px"
     *ngFor="let control of group.get('carPartSubCategories').controls"
    >
    <input type="text" [formControl]="control" />
   </div>
 </form>
</ng-container>
```

I created a stackblitz for you to see the result [stackblitz / reactive forms](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upxydg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: hi thanks for the detailed answer! can i ask you one more question? as i said i am doing inline editing, so i need to pass id to the update button that is stored inside items, how can i make that happened based on ur code? here is the forked stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-serl1g?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Here it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqc2uy?file=src/app/app.component.html